# How to hide selectizeInput if condition is not met in shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I am having problem when condition is meet, I want to hid selectizeInput from website. However, I am not able to do it. Due to nature of reactivity. I had to put following code in server.R file.

```
output$Super <- if(is.null(session$user)){
   renderUI({  

        selectizeInput("Salesperson"
                 , "Salesperson:"
                 , sort(getUsers())
                 , selected = 'All'
                 , NULL
                 , multiple =FALSE)
})
}else if(session$user == 'tester'){
 renderUI({
  selectizeInput("Salesperson"
                 , "Salesperson:"
                 , sort(getUsers())
                 , selected = 'All'
                 , NULL
                 , multiple =FALSE)
})

} else {
   renderUI({
      selectizeInput("Salesperson"
               , "Salesperson:"
               , session$user
               , selected = session$user
               , NULL
               , multiple =FALSE)
})
  }
```

Following line in ui.R

```
 conditionalPanel(
    condition ="input.Salesperson == 'All",
    uiOutput('Super')
  )
```

However, I don't want to renderUI if it fell in else statement. However, I am not able to do it. if I remove renderUI code from else. it crash it.

What I am doing wrong ?

Comment: Have you considered [`conditional panels`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13313503/2572423)?

Comment: I tried to use conditionalPanel in ui.R. However, condition is not working for me.  following code is for conditionalPanel                             conditionalPanel(
        condition ="input.Salesperson == 'All",
        uiOutput('Super')
      )

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to/can't use conditional panels, you can use the `hide()`+`show()` (or the `toggle()`) functions in `shinyjs` package